# Ratings & Reviews on launch of application

Tags: android, google-play

I want give option to user rate my app when they launch application.
I want to take them to "Ratings & Reviews" directly,if they want rate.

My question is it possible to direct the user to play stores "Ratings & Reviews"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to send them directly to "Ratings & Reviews" now. Google Play doesn't provide such an option/API. Only thing you can do is direct to the app page in Google Play.

Yes it would have been a great advantage if this was possible.